# generic regexp using jquery variable to replace dot, colon or any other character

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a jquery code that trims the leading and trailing character (passed from the calling program). I am using a variable in RegExp to replace the character with blank. How can I make the RegExp work for any character passed from the calling program? Here is the simplified code:

```
var time = ":1h:45m:34s:";
var chr= ':'; //can have . or , or any other character
var regex = new RegExp("(^" + chr + ")|(" + chr+ "$)" , "g"); //works for colon but not for dot.
//var regex = new RegExp("(^/" + chr + ")|(/" + chr+ "$)" , "g"); //for dot I added / but not for colon.
var formattedtime = time.replace(regex, "");
```

Expected Outputs:

```
1. time = ":1h:45m:34s:"; 
chr = ":";
Output: 1h:45m:34s
2. time = "1h:45m:34s"; 
chr = ":";
Output: 1h:45m:34s
3. time = ".45m.34s"; 
chr = ".";
Output: 45m.34s
4. time = "1h.45m.34s."; 
chr = ".";
Output: 1h.45m.34s
```

How can I make the regexp work for any character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape meta characters (like `.` and several others) to get literals. You do that by adding a backslash before them.

JS doesn't have any built in function for that, so you could use this:

```
function quotemeta(str){
    return str.replace(/[.+*?|\\^$(){}\[\]-]/g, '\\$&');
}
```

Used like so:

```
new RegExp("^(?:" + quotemeta(chr) + ")+|(?:" + quotemeta(chr) + ")+$" , "g");
```

Comment: I did that as in the commented line in my code snippet. `var regex = new RegExp("(^/" + chr + ")|(/" + chr+ "$)" , "g");` This works great for dot but not for colon. You mean I have to check the character and escape for each???

Comment: `/` is not a backslash, `\ ` is. But you can't use it on every character, because they have special meaning, eg `\s` means any white space.

Comment: Ah, this utility method is great. It can handle many characters. More generic approach. How can I understand the RegExp you provided?

Comment: It just matches any number of those characters at the beginning or end of string. I used a non-capturing group `(?:...)` in case it's not just one character, but a string. If you want to remove many different characters at once you can use a character class instead of the group, like `[abc]` will match one of `a`, `b` or `c`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var chr= ':/';
...    
var regex = new RegExp("(^[" + chr + "])|([" + chr+ "]$)" , "g");
```

Comment: This is a cool solution. It works for me. I am not that good with RegExp. Do you mind explaining this?

Comment: Use [] to define a set of characters, eg [:/.] matches on : / or .

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question, as I thought you wanted to remove a set of characters by using only one expression.

Comment: Pat, sorry if I made it sound silly.. Qtax's solution seems to be working for various characters and I wanted a generic solution to handle different characters. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Regex should this way:-

For Colon, `/^(\:)|(\:)$/gim`

For Dot, `/^(\.)|(\.)$/gim`

**OR**

```
/^(\:|\w|\.)|(\:|\w|\.)$/gim
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EaSXj/)**