# Highlighting variable word in a string using regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var stringToHighlight = [userinput] // may be any string like "foo", "bar" or "."
var stringToBeHighlighted = [any text] // Lorem Ipsum ...
```

So far I have

```
var regex = new RegExp(stringToHighlight, "g")                  
var highlightedString = stringToBeHighlighted.replace(regex, "<span class='highlight'>$&</span>")
```

This doesn't work for the character "." for example, because it is being interpreted as the regular expression metacharacter . but not the actual character "." resulting in all the text being highlighted. How do I exclude those special metacharacters?

Comment: possible duplicate of [generic regexp using jquery variable to replace dot, colon or any other character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620131/generic-regexp-using-jquery-variable-to-replace-dot-colon-or-any-other-characte)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS doesn't have any built in function to escape meta characters in regex, but you could use this function (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9620214/107152)):

```
function quotemeta(str){
    return str.replace(/[.+*?|\\^$(){}\[\]-]/g, '\\$&');
}
```

Which would be used like so:

```
var regex = new RegExp(quotemeta(stringToHighlight), "g");
```

Answer (score 0):

You either need to type in an actual regular expression (escape the "." by placing "\" before it) or you can use a function such as http://phpjs.org/functions/strstr:551 to look for a string literal