# Highlight matched text with case sensitive for auto suggestion

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, mustache

I am working for auto suggestion, where i need to match the key term and if the key term matched make it highlighted. I am done with this but the problem is while matching I am looking with ignore case. so In result if i am looking for **home** and result is Home its become **home** while displaying on fronend. I am using mustache as a templating engine for Ui.
Used code is:

```
var highLightRegExp = new RegExp(r.q , "ig");
//r.q - is query term.
            // Highlight the query part of the search term
            highlightText : function () {
              return function (text, render) {
                var renderTxt = render(text),
                    decodedText = $("<div/>").html(renderTxt).text();
                return decodedText.replace(highLightRegExp , "<b class='colorFFF'>" + r.q + "</b>");
              };
            }
```

How to match all the characters but while displaying it should be in original case.

Comment: Use a regular expression that forces matching based on the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$&` (which is the matched substring) in the replacement instead of the original string.

For example:

```
decodedText.replace(highLightRegExp , "<b class='colorFFF'>$&</b>");
```

Also don't forget to [escape the string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11001067/107152) before using it as an expression, or you could get some issues when user uses regex meta characters (`[home]*`).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `$&`:

> ***`$&`***
>   Substitutes a copy of the whole match.

sample code:

```
decodedText.replace(highLightRegExp , "<b class='colorFFF'>$&</b>");
```

or if you used `()` to grouping subexpression  match use `$1`:

> ***`$number`***
>   Substitutes the substring matched by group number.

sample code:

```
decodedText.replace(highLightRegExp , "<b class='colorFFF'>$1</b>");
```